# Home brew installation failing on macOS Catalina

Tags: github, installation, homebrew, failed-installation

When I enter the below installation command on terminal:

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

This is what I get:

[image: Terminal Output]

What can I try next?

Comment: What OS are you on - Linux or Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you can access the URL without issue and that your sudo gives you write access to the /etc/ssl/cert.pem file?

Comment: for the URL just copy/paste it into your browser and see if it opens. For the .pem file, try top open it from the terminal with "sudo nano /etc/ssl/cert.pem" at the end of the file write a few characters, save the file (don't quit the editor), if that works you're good. Remove the characters you added, then resave the file and quit the editor.